# Unix find and replace all with a condition

Tags: bash, perl, shell, unix, sed

I have a condition where I want to find and replace all '/ ' (forward / with a space after that) in a file for some lines having a specific entries. Example below:

```
g aaa / cccc dd
k eee / hhhh dd
m aaa / kkkk ll
```

I want to replace '/ ' with '/' for the rows with 'aaa' entry.

Comment: With sed you can do `sed '/aaa/s/bb/zz/g' file`

Comment: Magic... Thanks a lot

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37518/67817

Comment: @user000001 I guess you should turn that into an answer, unless there's a dupe on this site (which I'm pretty sure there will be!)

Comment: `awk '$2~/^aaa$/ {gsub(/ bb/, " zz")} {print}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
perl -pe '/aaa/ and s[/ ][/]'
```

Of course it can be refined in many ways, e.g., add `g` to the `s[][]` to replace all matches, add the `-i` switch to edit files “in place”, etc.